# How to make a macro as the value of a key in \pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I want to make a key by `\pgfkeys` whose value is a macro. But the following try fails. Please see my question in the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  halign/.code=#1,
  halign/.default=\centering,
  width/.initial,
  width/.default=4in
}
\newcommand\test[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{width,#1}
    \fbox{\parbox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/width}}{\pgfkeys{/halign} some text}}
}
\test\\
\test[halign=AAA]\\% Why is "AAA" out of the box?

\end{document}
```

Why is the following version not able to get what I want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  halign/.initial={}, halign/.default={},
  width/.initial=4in,
}
\newcommand\test[1][]{{%
  \pgfkeys{halign,#1}%
  \fbox{\parbox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/width}}{\pgfkeys{/halign} some text}}%
}}
\test[width=2in,halign=AAA]\\
\test[halign=\raggedleft]\\
\test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use some `pgfkeys` (a standalone package which is auto loaded by `pgf`) key to hold some value, generally one can use

- `key/.initial=<init value>` to initialize a key,
- `key=<new value>` to update the stored value, and finally
- `\pgfkeysvalueof{<full path>}` to retrieve the stored value.

So in OP's example,

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgfkeys}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}
% init keys
\pgfkeys{
  halign/.initial=\centering,
  width/.initial=4in,
}
\newcommand\test[1][]{{% use an extra group of braces to restrict the scope
  % locally modify keys
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  % use keys
  \fbox{\parbox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/width}}{\pgfkeys{/halign} some text}}%
}}
\test \\
\test[halign=AAA] \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

When `halign` is defined by `halign/.code=#1`, `\pgfkeys{halign=AAA}` will output `AAA`, which results in `AAA` out of the box.

Comment: Many thanks @muzimuzhi Z for your help. I still do not quite understand why `halign/.code=#1` results in `AAA` out of box? And what's the meaning of `use an extra group of braces to restrict the scope`

Comment: @lyl 1) With `\test[halign=AAA]`, `halign=AAA` is the first argument of `\test`. Then in `\test` `\pgfkeys{halign=AAA}` is called, which will typeset `AAA`. Note this `AAA` is typeset before `\fbox`. 2) With `\newcommand\test[1][]{\pgfkeys{#1}...}`, the change taken by `\pgfkeys{#1}` will influence following use of `\test`. With `\newcommand\test[1][]{{\pgfkeys{#1}...}}` (note the `{...}` added), the change is local.

Comment: Thank you so much!! And which is the better for group, `{...}` or `\begingroup...\endgroup`?

Comment: @lyl No difference and either works. If the enclosed content is rather long, then the longer hence more  obvious `\begingroup ... \endgroup` might be preferable.

Comment: Another question, Why is it wrong when adding `halign/.default={},`  to the `\pgfkeys` with `\pgfkeys{halign,#1}`other than`\pgfkeys{#1}` in the defination of \test by which I want to initialize the value each time to avoid polutioning the argument

Comment: @lyl I think that's because `halign` is defined by `/.code`, not `/.initial`.

Comment: I mean` \pgfkeys{ halign/.initial={},halign/.default={},width/.initial=4in,`

Comment: @lyl Ah it's not wrong, just another way. The only difference I can tell is, `\pgfkeys{halign, width, #1}` might be a little slower than `{\pgfkeys{#1} ... }`, especially when you have a long list of keys to reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133827/discussion-between-lyl-and-muzimuzhi-z).

Comment: I just give anoter full version to explain my question in detail. Why is this version not able to get what I want?

Comment: @lyl In `\fbox`, you should use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/halign}`, instead `\pgfkeys{/halign}` is used.

Comment: I'm puzzled. In your solution, `\pgfkeys{/halign}`, but here must be `\pgfkeysvalueof{/halign}`. Any further introduction for these?

Comment: @lyl With `halign/.initial=<val>` only, `\pgfkeys{halign}` will use `<val>`. But when `halign/.default=<val2>` is additionally used, `\pgfkeys{halign}` is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{halign=<val2>}`. Note the `pgfmanual` is wrong about the relation of `/.initial` and `/.default`, see issue [pgf#1133](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1133).

Comment: But I have changed the value of `halign` by `\test[width=2in,halign=AAA]`. I mean the value of `halign` now is `AAA` other than its default value. Why does this change not work?

Comment: @lyl Because with `halign/.initial={}, halign/.default={}`, `\pgfkeys{/halign}` is _setting_ `halign` to its default value, not retrieving its value. Hence the value of `halign` is changed twice per use of `\test`, but never used. The key point of my previous comment is, `halign/.default` _changes_ the behavior of `\pgfkeys{/halign}` from retrieving value to setting value.